# How do I find the source or a rogue character on my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, firefox

I have a very simple web-based internal tool. It has a total of 20 lines of css and 40 of js.

Something is inserting a '}' character on the page, that is not visible in the html

This is a screen shot from the page:

[image: screenshot shows and extra } before a table]

Here is an excrept of the html as sent to the client:

```
<div id="content">

<h2>Global State</h2>
<!-- before tag-->
<!--table start--> 
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
```

As you can see there are no }'s between the header and the table. You can see the 2 comments I've added to the templates to try to debug this.

Here is what the dom looks like in the browser debug:

[image: picture of a DOM tree showing a } between 2 comments and a table tag]

And there is it nestled between the comments and the table tag.

As I said, there are 20 lines of super simple css in this project. Just enough to give the tables borders and color some alerts red. There is a very little bit of js, to power some forms and buttons, but none of it points at this table and most of it isn't on this page. Ive been over both with a fine toothed comb.

This seems really minor, but it's driving to distraction.

Where else might this rogue } becoming from?

Can I get firefox to tell me the source?

Additional debugging information: There was indeed a } further down the page, in the `<table>` but not in a `<td>` or `<th>`.

Comment: Probably inside those 40 lines of JS. Please add those lines to your question.

Comment: For this type of problem you may be able to save a local copy of the page source, make sure that the local copy exhibits the problem, then cut sections out of it until the problem goes away, then you'll have identified the problem section. Keep dividing that into smaller sections until you find the root cause.

Comment: To the mod who closed this: It demonstrably did NOT need more debugging information because the information provided was enough for @alochi to provide a solution. This itchy trigger finger closing is part of what's ruining this site as a place to get help. I was luck to get a answer before the close-every-queston brigaid got it.

Comment: The fact alochi was able to come up with a guess as to the problem does not demonstrate this should not have been closed. You should have included a [mre] in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `}` will be somewhere inside the mark-up of your table, but not between `<td>` and `</td>` tags. The HTML parser ejects this from the table and moves it to before the table in a process called [foster parenting](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#foster-parent) , which is where you see it in the DOM document.

Comment: Yes this was it, thanks. I don't usually work on front end. I'm mostly a backend guy. I was just doing the frontend on this because it's an internal tool and mostly backend. I didn't even know that foster parenting was a thing. (It's a little funny because the feature I'm working on is called 'orphan adoption'.)